# How can I get a value without the '[ ]'

Tags: python, pandas

```
file_name = 'employee_handbook.csv'
cid = 2603704587

with open(file_name, newline = '') as handbook:
    emp_handbook = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(file_name))
    row_number = emp_handbook[emp_handbook['CID'] == cid].index.values
    name = emp_handbook.iloc[row_number,[1]].values
print(name)
```

Output:

```
[['Jun Cheng']]
```

How can I get `'Jun Cheng'` instead of `[['Jun Cheng']]`

Comment: `print(name[0][0])`

Answer (score 1):

you need to

```
print(yourlist[0][0][0])
```

the number of bracket pairs with 0 in them is the number of lists you want to index into to find the string

for example

```
a = [['2222']]

print(a[0][0])
```

Comment: you can always change the 0 values depending on its position of the item in the list.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code :

```
file_name = 'employee_handbook.csv'
cid = 2603704587

emp_handbook = pd.read_csv(file_name)
name = emp_handbook.loc[lambda df: df.CID == cid, 'name'].iloc[0]

print(name)
```

Also in your case:

- there is no need to use a `with` statement
- the return value of `pd.read_csv` is already a `DataFrame` so there is no need to add `pd.DataFrame`.